# Creating a bot that manages currency for both a twitch chat and a discord server

Tags: node.js, discord.js, twitch

I've built the currency system for both discord and twitch independently in node.js. I want my currency system to carry over between the two. The hard part is both discord and twitch use different user ids so I can't use one JSON file to manage both. Is there a way I can match up user ids easily (like if they have their twitch connected to the discord) or will I have to pair them up one by one manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **NO EASY** way todo this...

You will have to request each *new* user to *connect* their account...
 
How you can do this:
Step 1: ask them if they have a twitch account. If they dont you cant connect em
Step 2: send them a random sentence. EG:(Spiders Balloony Video Moles Havoc) (in DM)
Step 3: Ask them to repeat this sentence in a chat that the bot shares.
Step 4: When you find the sentence in the opposite chat you now know the user.

If twitch has DM chat you can do this vice versa as well! (I do not have a twitch account so I do not know if twitch has private chat)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment that's not possible, because in order to see users' connections (like Twitch profile, YouTube channel and so on...) you'd need a self-bot (that can get you banned from Discord).
Discord Dreamland has an active idea on this topic: [link](https://feedback.discordapp.com/forums/326712-discord-dream-land/suggestions/19518943-api-view-user-profile-on-a-bot-account)

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51354531/getting-user-profile-connections-with-a-bot-account) other question